# Block "cloner" servers rendering content from our server

Tags: apache, seo, clone, cracking

I have a website of mine (freeofficefinder.com) that is being cloned (see here: thelawyerserviceratings.org)  There are actually over 25 websites that are currently cloning our website.

Obviously this is hurting our SEO ranking greatly due to "duplicate content".  Is there something that I could add to the Apache config file to ensure that only our website is rendered at the domain freeofficefinder.com.  And for all other domains this is blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see, you web server configured to serve the same virtual host for any requested server name.

Example:

```
# telnet freeofficefinder.com 80
Trying 78.109.169.208...
Connected to freeofficefinder.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: blablabla.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 10 Jun 2015 15:54:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9
Set-Cookie: device_view=full
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=qbe8aar8b58ckr9nvlqbnsdgd2; expires=Wed, 10-Jun-2015 16:54:30 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Cache-Control: max-age=0, public, s-maxage=604800
X-Content-Digest: en7c017d952f04b31ac9f09a61d0ed6561fd153e3549cdf743cbb277e2db847bab
Content-Length: 17105
Age: 0
Set-Cookie: device_view=full; expires=Thu, 09-Jul-2015 23:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=2531130; path=/; httponly
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

... content ...
```

This means, anybody can set A-record to your web server IP (78.109.169.208) and your site will work on any domain.
The cause is you use an asterisk `*` as a ServerName
Look through your Apache configs, find `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives, having `*` as a value, and replace `*` with your actual host name (freeofficefinder.com).

Then add another one `<VirtualHost>` section **above** yours and set a `ServerName *` for it. This special section will serve requests for all unknown domains like "thelawyerserviceratings.org" etc. You can put there some funny content.

Comment: I tried doing as you mentioned see here: http://i.imgur.com/o02WuIO.png However I had to comment out the first part due to an error "Invalid ServerName "*" use ServerAlias to set multiple server names." However when I did this: http://i.imgur.com/i00laS5.png it worked... but sadly freeofficefinder.com also showed the "spam" website. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm... try to remove `ServerAlias *` from the first virtualhost. It should catch "unknown" domains in any case.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That has worked! Had to use an awesome pic of Cartman for those spammy sites ;-) thelawyerserviceratings.org

Comment: Very nice :) *Thumbs*